# How to reconfigure PHPJobScheduler to perfom jobs after pretermined intervals independent off someone accessing your website

Tags: php, job-scheduling

I'm using phpjobscheduler to run a JSON fetching php script after every minute. However on its README its stated that it only runs your jobs provided that someone accesses the link to the php file where you have included the job scheduler script. How do I set it so that its scheduling goes on whether or not someone accesses your website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it does need to be fired from a page on a website (from a html or PHP file).  You can also fire it via a cron job.

There are lots more details here:
http://members.dwalker.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=919

BTW - hope you like phpjobscheduler, I first created it over 10 years ago:
http://www.phpjobscheduler.co.uk/demo/readme.html#history

Comment: Started using it and I like it. I was wondering though why make it to schedule only after site is accessed

Comment: Today morning I also got a notification that I could not create or modify and jobs until I upgrade to a newer version. That brought my site down for like 2 hours....please look into that

Comment: "That brought my site down for like 2 hours..."  NO IT MOST DEFINITELY DID NOT!!  I would thank you to not misinform others!

Comment: If you are using an out of date version of phpJobScheduler then the add/modify jobs will be disabled.  ALL OTHER FUNCTIONALITY remains unchanged.  If, in your words: "That brought my site down for like 2 hours..." then is has nothing to do with this application.  You should ask you host.  Also, I have up-voted your question, please  up-vote my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @DaveWalker i am having problem with running multiple jobs i only run the first of four jobs what could be the reason. i tried checking of the url in  `function fire_remote_script($url)` it echoed all 4 script url but only runs the first one